# Portable java solution for zipping/unzipping

Tags: java, zip, portability

I'm looking for a simple package that I may simply call from command line (i.e. batch script) that can mostly replace the functionality of zip/unzip tools in Linux.  Ideally, I'd be able to deploy the application (.jar file) to any machine that runs Java, tell it what to unzip and it does it's thing.  This seems like it should be fairly simple and I don't want to re-invent the wheel, but I can't seem to find something like this.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use `jar`. That's a zipping program.

Comment: @halfdan I'm not sure, but I guess `jar` is available only if a JDK is installed, not if only the JRE is installed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a ready tool, but you could easily (a single class probably) write your own unzip tool in Java using the classes from [java.util.zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html), e.g. the [ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class.

Comment: I guess I was just hoping someone had already done something like this - it seems so simple and nice to have it's surprising it doesn't exist.  Perhaps I'll do so more poking, and if I can't find anything I'll put something together and perhaps publish the code.

Answer (score 1):

The Ant tasks - [zip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) and [unzip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) should be of some benefit to you, if you don't want to completely re-invent the wheel.  You could either call them as part of Ant, or call the task implementations directly using Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and its brother ZipOutputStream if you want to build a tool yourself.

But seriously: what is the chance that you are running a tool on a system which does have Java installed, but does not have compression tools to perform zip and unzip?

Comment: Well, I for example wouldn't know how to start an unzip operation under Windows from a batch script.